# TDS sync always shows Items are different even after updataing

Tags: tds

I am trying to sync TDS with sitecore items but TDS sync always shows that Items are different even after updataing my sitecore items from project.

Is there a solution for same?

I am using 5.1.0.17 version of TDS

Here is the how it looks.

[image]

Comment: What are the differences it shows? Could you please include concrete examples?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I have added Image for your reference

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is the `created` field, which was added in Sitecore 8.1.3 and the earlier version of TDS are not able to handle this field correctly.

You should upgrade to the a newer version of TDS, 5.5.0.14 or higher, and it should resolve the issue after you re-synchronise.

> Fixed issue with Sitecore 8 update 3 "created" property in the .item file

You can get the latest version of TDS and see the release notes here:
http://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download

There is more details about this issue in this blog post:
http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2016/08/26/tds-sync-issues-with-8-1-update-3/

Comment: This is correct, but you shouldn't need to upgrade.  In any TDS version (at least for a long while) you can configure which fields it compares.  In VS go to Tools->Options->TDS Options->Sync Window, and you will see a field for adding/removing fields to compare when it diffs the items.  Just add an entry for 'created'.

Comment: @Jason: Normally yes, but that did not work for us. Upgrading fixed the issue.